# How to grouped/aggregate data in mongo dB to Make a Events

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongo data like this format

```
[
  { 
     _id:ObjectId("5f71890730a4421699b1fbff"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:07:52Z"),
    running_fig: "circle",
  },
  {
    _id:ObjectId("5f718ac330a4421699b1fc15"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:08:48Z"),
    running_fig: "circle",
  },
  {
    _id:ObjectId("5f718ac330a4421699b1fc16"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:09:32Z"),
    running_fig: "rombous",
  },
  {
    _id:ObjectId("5f718ac330a4421699b1fc14"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:10:11Z"),
    running_fig: "triangle",
  },
  {
    _id:ObjectId("5f718ac330a4421699b1fc13"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:11:52Z"),
    running_fig: "triange",
  },
  {
    _id:ObjectId("5f718ac330a4421699b1fc12"),  
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:15:22Z"),
    running_fig: "circle",
  },
  {
     _id:ObjectId("5f718ac330a4421699b1fc1e"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-12T03:20:52Z"),
    running_fig: "circle",
  },
  
]
```

** Now I want to make an events chart according to there running figure time, I expected to query result in below form I have given**

```
[
  {
running_fig:“circle”,
from: 2020-12-21T03: 07: 52Z,
to: 2020-12-21T03: 09: 48Z,
duration: 2 min.
  },
  {
running_fig:“rombous”,
from: 2020-12-21T03: 09: 48Z,
to: 2020-12-21T03: 10: 32Z,
duration: 1 min.
  },
  {
running_fig:“triangle”,
from: 2020-12-21T03: 10: 32Z,
to: 2020-12-21T03: 15: 22Z,
duration: 5 min.
  },
  {
running_fig:“circle”,
from: 2020-12-21T03: 15: 22Z,
to: 2020-12-21T03: 25: 52Z (current time),
duration: 10 min.
  }
]
```

so I want result data in this format so I can create a chart accordingly, in this data my chart
running_fig circle start_time is own timestamps and its end_time will next running_fig Timestamps
in my case next rhombus coming so the duration of running_fig circle is (3:09 -3:07) = 2 minutes and they combine into single data show my expected result.
anybody pls help me achieve this query, Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is the first circle ending at `2020-12-21T03:09:48Z` ? I don't see where the times comes from. Same applies for other times.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you for your consideration in this case data are continues coming. when the running_fig value change in my case circle to Rombous means at the start_time of the circle(3:07) & start_time of Rombous(3:09) between this duration circle is coming in running_fig so its duration is 3 min. same applies all.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Please provide exact input data according to desired output.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for replying. actually my sensor log data into MongoDB on data change, I have around 10 parameters to log when any parameter change it to log all data into my database that why I get the same  2020-12-21T03:09:48Z

Comment: I still don't get your logic. Most likely you have to work with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/). Certainly it will contain expression `{$last: "$$value."$timestamp"}`

Comment: Input data and expected result data does not match . Please provide correct data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tedious solution.

**Explanation**

1. Put data into array (assuming you are getting data from sensor 1)
2. Sort by timestamp
3. check pre index in array, if pre index running_fig =  current index running_fig remove this data from array.
4. Add next index data.
5. if next index timestamp is null add current timestamp

Code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** group by machine name*/
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$sensor",
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },
    
  },
  /** sort by date to make event list*/
  {
    $sort: {
      "docs.timestamp": -1
    }
  },
  /** get pre data*/
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        /** transform the "docs" field*/
        $map: {
          /** into something*/
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$docs"
              }
            ]
          },
          /** an array from 0 to n - 1 where n is the number of documents*/
          as: "this",
          /** which shall be accessible using "$$this"*/
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              /** we join two documents*/
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$docs",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              },
              /** one is the nth document in our "docs" array*/
              {
                "pre_index": {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      "$gte": [
                        {
                          "$subtract": [
                            "$$this",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$docs",
                        {
                          "$subtract": [
                            "$$this",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        
                      ]
                    },
                    null
                  ]
                },
                index: "$$this"
              }/** and the second document is the one with our "index" field*/
              
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /**remove same state data*/
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      noDuplicateArray: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$docs",
          as: "a",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$a.running_fig",
              "$$a.pre_index.running_fig"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /**add next data*/
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        /** transform the "docs" field*/
        $map: {
          /** into something*/
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$noDuplicateArray"
              }
            ]
          },
          /** an array from 0 to n - 1 where n is the number of documents*/
          as: "this",
          /** which shall be accessible using "$$this"*/
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              /** we join two documents*/
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$noDuplicateArray",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              },
              /** one is the nth document in our "docs" array*/
              {
                "to": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$noDuplicateArray",
                    {
                      $add: [
                        "$$this",
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    
                  ]
                },
                index: "$$this"
              }/** and the second document is the one with our "index" field*/
              
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$docs._id",
      sensor: "$_id",
      from: "$docs.timestamp",
      to: {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$docs.to.timestamp",
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      },
      running_fig: "$docs.running_fig",
      duration: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $toString: {
              $round: [
                {
                  $divide: [
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        {
                          "$ifNull": [
                            "$docs.to.timestamp",
                            "$$NOW"
                          ]
                        },
                        "$docs.timestamp"
                      ]
                    },
                    60000
                  ]
                },
                1
              ]
            }
          },
          " min"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo Playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/CxHNdO6vLop

Comment: I thing the `$sort` must come before the `$group` - and there is not `date` field anyway.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit what is the performance parameter if million of data

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned your sample data does not match the expected result, so it is difficult to understand the logic. But this aggregation should show the direction it may go.

Version with using `$reduce`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
   // Transform documents to array
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   // combine timestamp with previous timestamp
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: ["$$value",
                     [{
                        running_fig: "$$this.running_fig",
                        from: "$$this.timestamp",
                        to: { $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.from" }, "$$NOW"] }
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $sort: { "data.from": 1 } },
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT.data" } } },
   // find consequtive running_fig
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: ["$$value",
                     [{
                        $cond: {
                           if: { $ne: [{ $last: "$$value.running_fig" }, "$$this.running_fig"] },
                           then: "$$this",
                           else: null
                        }
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // remove null values from array
   { $set: { data: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $ne: ["$$this", null] } } } } },
   { $unwind: "$data" }
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

Version with using `$map` and `$range`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$data" }] },
               as: "idx",
               in:
                  {
                     $cond: {
                        if: {
                           $ne: [
                              { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.running_fig", "$$idx"] },
                              { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.running_fig", { $add: ["$$idx", 1] }] }
                           ]
                        },
                        then: {
                           running_fig: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.running_fig", "$$idx"] },
                           from: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.timestamp", "$$idx"] },
                           to: { $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$data.timestamp", { $add: ["$$idx", 1] }] }, "$$NOW"] }
                        },
                        else: null
                     }
                  }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { data: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $ne: ["$$this", null] } } } } },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
]);
```

Comment: very very thanks I am expecting the same. one more question I have to ask if I have billions of data so which method is more efficient. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Using `$map` is clearly faster, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53503